# How to handle PackageManager has died exception (DeadObjectException)

Tags: android, package-managers, android-package-managers

My app listens to app installs and uninstalls and whenever such an event occurs it updates some data. Here's what I do:

```
String appPackageName = ...; // new app's package name
PackageManager pm = MainApp.get().getPackageManager();

// update installed apps list
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> ril = null;
try {
    ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // what to do now???
    // I need the info, I can't silently ignore it...
}

// continue using the data => in my case I update my database and add the new installed app
```

I get following exception:

```
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:3949)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:801)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:850)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:793)
    at... // => at ABOVE CODE BLOCK at ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

I frist thought this only happens if my app is updating itself, but it seems like it isn't. A user told me that this happens everytime he installs a new app (not if he uninstalls an app and installs it again).

Any ideas what can I do here?

Comment: do you have any insights regarding that issue?